# React application with Service Worker - Force update of browser cache on new version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, service-worker, workbox

My app is written in Reac / Redux and uses Workbox to generate my service worker.
This works - I can confirm revision is updated in the generated service worker when running "workbox inject:manifest".

However, I have noticed clients are not updating the cache after a new release, new code will only load after several refreshes. For each release I have confirmed that the revision is updated.

The things I have tried so far to force the browser to clear the cache after a new release are:

- Implemented skipWaiting() in my ServiceWorker - shows update alert correctly
- Added cache headers to disable caching of the serviceWorker.js and css files (see below)
- Added [contenthash] to all my bundle files in Webpack and updated index.html accordingly for each release

Cache headers

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
    
  <IfModule mod_alias.c>
    # disable browser cache for serviceWorker.js file
    <FilesMatch "^(serviceWorker.js)$">
      Header unset Expires
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0"
    </FilesMatch>
    
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
      # cache for 24 hours = 86400 seconds
      Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, no-transform, must-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

index.html

```
...
<body style="overflow: hidden">
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/main.bundle.aae6d2bb162cbee13899.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/0.bundle.aaa837f16bb646266d99.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/1.bundle.aa653fe9abbe232be599.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/2.bundle.aa3096daabb2d428a899.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/3.bundle.aa1650fc5bb4e1f1ea99.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/4.bundle.aae80e50cbb06d5e5599.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/5.bundle.aa1824b9ebb0cb931b99.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        Sorry, this page requires javascript!
     </noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Despite all these solutions the app still caches in all tested browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari) **and** in the PWA. The cache will only refresh after one or more reloads and/or hard reload.

I have also verified that the bundle file hash have changed for updated code between releases.

Example of old file **before** code update and deploy

```
5.bundle.aa1824b9ebb0cb931b99.js
```

Example of new file **after** code update and deploy

```
5.bundle.cae6d2bb162cbee138bc.js
```

The reference in `index.html` to the bundle file is updated with the new hash, but the browser still tries to fetch the old file - resulting in fatal error `"ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk [n.oldHash] failed."`.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there any other way to force the browser (and PWA) to **refresh all code after a new release**?

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed similar principles as mentioned in this post to clear my cache. I just made the request on a setInterval rather than wrapping the app in a clear cache HOC. https://dev.to/ammartinwala52/clear-cache-on-build-for-react-apps-1k8j the article this links to also has some good examples, it is worth looking at both. https://dev.to/flexdinesh/cache-busting-a-react-app-22lk

Not sure if this is the best approach, but it works for me

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will test HOC approach described in the article! (^___^)/

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick in order to foce cash , by adding a get parameter for each new version , like this :

`<script src="/dist/5.bundle.aa1824b9ebb0cb931b99.js?v=2"></script>`

not that the value of v must be changed in every deployment (you can automate it)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the tip. \(^__^)/  However, even when the file hash changes the new file is not picked up by the browser. ( ? ) I have clarified my question to reflect this. Kind regards /K